# What are the requirements to make the admin toolbar show up on the front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I have done some weird things with a few custom theme pages. Namely, i have bypassed the wp_query and obtained data from a different db. I populate the post object with custom data and then inject this into my theme. Since the toolbar shows up fine normally, there must be some sort of trigger that i am bypassing by not calling the wordpress DB. I am 100% sure the theme is not the cause of the issue here, it is the messing that i have done. However, there are no errors in the code, everything works good. What does the admin toolbar require in order to load? Is there some hook i can call manually in order to make it render?

I have tried messing around with the code and info from the wordpress docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar . Since none of this has worked, the only thing i can think of is that there are some requirements that need to be met in order for the admin bar to be rendered and by bypassing the things i have bypassed, those requirements are not met, so i need to figure out how to spoof it

Comment: You said you did some "weird" things to few custom theme pages. Is the admin bar missing only on these pages?

Comment: Yes only missing on the pages that I bypass the standard flow. What I do is I included the wordpress code, call init and then I grab global post. I populate this object with custom.data then call get_header and get_footer

Comment: Have you tried to reset global post with wp_reset_postdata();?

Comment: I have not. I do not need to use wp_query as I have nothing to obtain from the WordPress DB. Does the admin bar have some.connection to this query?

Comment: Not really sure, I suggested that since you mentioned that you grabbed the global post and that function restores it.